# Ajax + Vue.js: Sending data to PHP file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, vue.js

I would like to send data to a php file from my Vue application to eventually save the data in a JSON file. If I understand it right, I can use JQuery/Ajax to do so as in any other non-vue application:

```
methods: { postData() {

    $.ajax({
      url: 'http://localhost:8080/test.php',
      type: 'POST',
      data: {
        data: {name: "test", age: "test"}
      },
      complete: function(data, status) {
        if (status == 'success') {
          console.log('saved!');
        } else {
          console.log('Error has been occurred');
        }
      }
    });

  }
},
```

I placed the test.php file in the public folder:

```
<?php print_r($_POST); ?>
```

If I open http://localhost:8080/test.php, my browser does download the file. However, my vue app returns http://localhost:8080/test.php 404 (Not Found) in the console.

Where do I need to place the php file? Can this work at all? Grateful for any hints!

Edit:
I served the file from another port. In my Vue app, I execute this code in the mounted hook:

```
   mounted() {
      $.ajax({
        url: 'http://localhost:8888/test.php',
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        type: 'post',
        data: '{ "name":"test", "age":30, "city":"test" }',
        success: function( data ){
            console.log(data)
        },
        error: function(errorThrown){
          console.error(
              errorThrown
          );

        }
      });
    }
```

This throws a 200 error in the console.
My file test.php simply contains the following line:

```
<?php
echo($_POST);
?>
```

If I open it in my browser, it says `Array`:
[test.php screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U08JA.png)

Comment: Vue.js would run on a different port and PHP server on a different one for local development.

Comment: Right, thanks, I now served it from another Port and it seems to work a litte further. Now getting  a "Error has been occurred".

Comment: We would need more context to understand the setup. Can you share the relevant code? You will need to pass [`CORS headers`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) now from your PHP script to the frontend(not vice-versa).

Comment: I edited the post again. There is really nothing more than these two files. I had a Cross-Origin-Error but adding ' dataType: 'jsonp' removed it.

Comment: So, what is the error you get? Any screenshots?

Comment: Sorry for the slow information. It's a 200 error. I know so little about php that I'm apparantly not aware which information is relevant

Comment: 200 ok status is not an error. It means everything is ok. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status

Comment: you're right! it was a JSON encode problem actually. Thanks!